# Finding the Angle of Intersection of elements from two images

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, imagej

I am trying to analyze the intersection points between two skeletonized, binary images.

(An example of the two images that need to be compared are linked here: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2itrjix&s=8#.VYwmeWA-CHo and http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2mhix38&s=8#.VYwmbWA-CHo)

Using Imagej I can easily find where all the intersect points are.

However, what I need to do in Matlab is find where these two images intersect and find out at what angle they intersect.

There are many intersection points on each image so it can't be a "manual" process for each intersection.

Once I know the angle of intersection I need to be able to sort the intersection points based on the calculated angle.

Any help is much appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "two images intersecting"? Do you mean which angles the intersection points intersect at?

Comment: Yes. In each of the skeletonized images there are a bunch of lines and if you compare them they intersect at various points. I want to find the angle at which the line segment from one image intersects with a line segment from the other image. Thanks!